# Extending a uniqueness argument for a system of first order linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, systems-of-equations

I'm following a uniqueness argument for a certain system of ordinary linear differential equations. The system is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{v_1} \\
\dot{v_2} \\
\dot{v_3} 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \kappa & 0 \\
-\kappa & 0 & \tau \\
0 & -\tau & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where each symbol represents a real-valued function defined on the interval $I: 0 \leq s \leq a$. By assumption, $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are continuous, and the extreme value theorem is invoked to get $k$ as an upper bound for the two.

It must be proven that two triplets of functions $(v_j)$ and $(v_j^*)$ which satisfy this system and such that $v_j(0) = v_j^*(0)$ are identical. My textbook only presents an argument that this is true in the subinterval $\tilde{I}$ of $I$ defined by $s \leq \frac{1}{2k}$. It goes as follows.

Let $s_j$ be that value of $s$ in $\tilde{I}$ for which $|v_j - v_j^*|$ assumes its maximum value, say $M_j$. We have

$$
\begin{split}
M_1 & = |v_1(s_1) - v_1^*(s_1)| \\
& = \left | \int_0^{s_1} (\dot{v}_1 - \dot{v}_1^*) ds \right | \\
& = \left | \int_0^{s_1} \kappa (v_2 - v_2^*)ds \right | \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2k} \cdot k \cdot M_2 \\
& = \tfrac{1}{2} M_2 .
\end{split}
$$

We similarly find that $M_2 \leq \tfrac{1}{2}(M_1 + M_3)$ and $M_3 \leq \tfrac{1}{2} M_2$. Adding the first and last of these inequalities, we find $M_1 + M_3 \leq \tfrac{1}{2} (M_1 + M_3)$. Since, by definition, $M_j \geq 0$, we have $M_j = 0$. This means that for all values of $s$ in $\tilde{I}$ the relations $v_j(s) = v_j^*(s)$ hold.

After this the textbook simply says "Repeating this argument we obtain $v_j(s) = v_j^*(s)$ for all values of $s$ in $I$". This would mean replacing occurrences of $\frac{1}{2k}$ with $a$ in the argument, ending with $M_1 + M_3 \leq 2 (ak)^2 (M_1 + M_3)$. My confusion comes from the possibility that $2(ak)^2 \geq 1$, for then it seems like no information is gained from this. How should this argument be properly extended to work as suggested?

Comment: I don’t follow your final paragraph. Just repeat the argument, starting at $x=1/2k$ instead of $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks so much that makes more sense than whatever I had going on. Just to be clear, you’re saying to repeat the argument for each interval given by $0 \leq \tfrac{1}{2k} \leq \tfrac{2}{2k} \leq \ldots \leq a$?

Comment: Yes, that’s the idea I had in mind ….